# How to determine column input based on value in another column in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate the process of entering information into excel columns. I have one particular instance where a column(AV) either has to be "Issue Audit Report With Findings" if another column(CG) has a value of 1 or higher or "Issue Audit Report with No Findings/Audit Closure Statement" if the column(CG) has a value of 0 or blank. I'm wondering how I would go about doing this.

here is my VBA code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(46)) Is Nothing Then
Dim arrHolidays, tmp As Single, rngN As Range, d As Date

If Target.Cells(1).Value = "Performed Audit" Then
     'place in an array all national holidays:
     arrHolidays = Array(CLng(CDate("2022-09-05")), CLng(CDate("2022-11-24")), CLng(CDate("2022-11-25")), CLng(CDate("2022-12-23")), _
                                  CLng(CDate("2022-12-26")), CLng(CDate("2022-12-28")), CLng(CDate("2022-12-29")), CLng(CDate("2022-12-30")))
    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Set rngN = Me.Cells(Target.Row, "N"):  d = rngN.Value
    tmp = CDbl(d) - Int(d) 'place the time in a variable. Workday does not return hours, minutes, seconds...
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
     Me.Cells(Target.Row, "J").Value = "Performed"
     Me.Cells(Target.Row, "K").Value = "Performed"
     Me.Cells(Target.Row, "AS").Value = "Post-Audit"
     Me.Cells(Target.Row, "AU").Value = Format(Me.Cells(Target.Row, "N"), "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
     Me.Cells(Target.Row, "AV").Value = "Issue Audit Report"
     Me.Cells(Target.Row, "AW").Value = Format(WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl(d + 19, 1, 1, arrHolidays) + tmp, "mm/dd/yyyy  HH:mm:ss")
    Me.Cells(Target.Row, "AZ").Value = Format(WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl(d + 19, 1, 1, arrHolidays) + tmp, "mm/dd/yyyy  HH:mm:ss")
    Me.Cells(Target.Row, "BA").Value = Format(WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl(d + 29, 1, 1, arrHolidays) + tmp, "mm/dd/yyyy  HH:mm:ss")
    Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End If
```

In particular the line that needs to be changed is

```
Me.Cells(Target.Row, "AV").Value = "Issue Audit Report"
```

Comment: Why don't you use a formula for this: `.Formula = ="IF(CG" & target.row & "=0,""Issue Audit Report with No Findings"", ""Issue audit Report With Findings"")"`

Comment: @Ike I've used VBA for everything so far but i'm not opposed to using column formulas. Are you suggesting I use something like nested IF statements for the AV column?

Comment: @Ike ok I see, i'll try it out